# Slf4j compatibility issues between solr and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, solr, slf4j, behemoth

I am using behemoth solr on hadoop, and I am getting a conflict in the slf4j versions. Solr 3.6.2 uses slf4j-api-1.6.1 and hadoop 1.0.4 has libraries for slf4j-api-1.4.3. Due to this, I am unable to run the behemoth solr jar file on hadoop. What is the best way to resolve this conflict? One option is replacing slf4j libraries in hadoop, but I am not willing to do that. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar with slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar in Hadoop without any problems as all versions of slf4j-api are compatible from the caller's point of view. See also the [relevant FAQ entry](http://slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch).